# How to create a new google spreadsheet through an app in react native?

Tags: react-native, google-sheets-api, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I am writing a simple app in which I would like to create a google spreadsheet when the user wants to.
I could only get to the part below, where I can read data from already existing google spreadsheets, but I'm not able to convert this such that, at the click of the button, I will be able to create a new google spreadsheet.
Can someone help me with the syntax I need to use?
Can I do this?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const API_KEY = '...';
const sheetID = '...';

class App extends Component {
  getSheetValues = async () => {
    const request = await fetch(
      `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${sheetID}/values/A1?key=${API_KEY}`
    );
    const data = await request.json();
    console.log(data);
    return data;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={this.getSheetValues}>Get sheet values</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: About `i will be able to create a new google spreadsheet`, unfortunately, new Spreadsheet cannot be created using the API key because in order to create the Spreadsheet, the POST method is required to be requested. The API key cannot be used for the POST method. So in your case, the access token is required to be used. How about this?

Comment: I wanted to know the syntax to use if i have the access token. I want to avoid the whole authorisation popup thing that comes up in the example on the google speadhsheet api guide.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `I want to avoid the whole authorisation popup thing that comes up in the example on the google speadhsheet api guide.`, in this case, I think that the service account and/or the Web Apps created by Google Apps Script might be able to be used. But in this case, I'm not sure which is better for your situation. I apologize for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the below code worked - now i want to find a way to refresh the access token automatically without going to https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground

```
'''
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  getSheetValues = async () => {
    const request = await fetch(
      `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${sheetID}/values/A1?key=${API_KEY}`
    );
    const data = await request.json();
    console.log(data);
    return data;
  };

  getNewSheet = async () => {
    const request = await fetch(
      `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets`,
      {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Authorization: `Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}`,
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          properties: {
            title: 'newSpreadSheetTest',
          },
        }),
      }
    );
    const data = await request.json();
    console.log(data);
    return data;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={this.getSheetValues}>Get Spreadsheet values</button>
        <br />
        <hr />
        <button onClick={this.getNewSheet}>Create New Spreadsheet</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
'''
```